# How to find the optimal cut point of a categorical variable?

Tags: categorical-data, binning, barplot

I have two categorical variables (x and z) as shown in the frequency plot below. Y-axis is the count of variable x.

[image: bar plot]

As evident in this plot, there is a clear relationship between x and z variables. I am interested in finding the optimal value of `z` variable, which is the tipping point, after which the probability of x variable will increase drastically to fall on the positive side of x-axis.

By looking at the plot, I can clearly see that, when the z variable is below the range of `[-0.977, 2.173)`, there is a high probability that `x` variable will be a positive value and when the `z` variable is above this range, then there is a high probability that x variable will be a negative value.

Is there any statistical test or any other technique to find out the most suitable cut point (`[-0.977, 2.173)` in this case) of the `z` variable?

Comment: What are you trying to optimize for? What would be the best possible outcome?

Comment: Best possible outcome is [-0.977, 2.173).

Comment: What makes that the best outcome?

Comment: The reason it is the best outcome is when the z variable is below the range of [-0.977, 2.173), there is a high probability that x variable will be a positive value and when the z variable is above this range, then there is a high probability that x variable will be a negative value.

Comment: That is unlikely to replicate in a new dataset.  The search for cutpoints that may not even exist is one of the best ways to waste time and create unstable results.